# Scala project class showing Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, oop, functional-programming

I am new to scala, I am using eclipse as an IDE and  I want to create a class in scala,

```
package com.scalaCode.example;

class Person(first: String, last: String) {

  var id: Int = _

  var firstName: String = first

  var lastName: String = last

  def this() = this(null, null)

  override def toString = id + " = " + firstName + " " + lastName

}
```

but eclipse IDE is indicating error mark saying

```
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
```

Is my IDE is treating this class as Java code?

Actually i want to create a scala web project. To do so i configured java web project to scala web project by editing .project file and replacing

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder with org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder
```

and added  Scala nature to your project:

```
<nature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</nature>
```

Seeking for immediate help...

Comment: What's the file extension? Should be `.scala`

Comment: yes , it is ".scala" itself, tried several things like cleaning code, configuring build path but yet not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Tried building through command propmt, restarted eclipse and it worked.